# c# DataContractSerializer issue

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I'm pulling data from a restful service which returns XML in the form of

```
<CollectionOfItems>
  <Item>
    <Param1>param1 value</Param1>
    <Param2>param2 value</Param2>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Param1>param1 value</Param1>
    <Param2>param2 value</Param2>  
  </Item>
</CollectionOfItems>
```

This Is The Method I'm using to consume the rest service

```
public object getMetaData(string uri, Type type)
    {
        //Create Object To Be Returned
        object result = null;
        //Create Web Request
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
        //Get Response
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (request.HaveResponse && response != null)
            {
                using (Stream reader = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    DataContractSerializer xmlSer = new DataContractSerializer(type);

                    result = xmlSer.ReadObject(reader);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I have a class to match the `<CollectionOfItems>`

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "CollectionOfItems", Namespace = "http://matchingnamespace")]
    public class CollectionOfItems: List<Item>
    {
    }
```

And a class to hold the `<Item>`

```
[DataContract(Name="Item")]
    public class Item
    {
        [DataMember(Name="Param1")]
        public string param1{ get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="Param2")]
        public string param2{ get; set; }
    }
```

My problem is that when I bind the result to a Listbox I end up with an object that has the correct number of results but I only see the results as blank lines.  I seem to have a `<CollectionOfItems>` with the correct amount of `<Item>` but I don't see any values for param1 or param2 etc....

Comment: Could you show us how you are binding the result to the ListBox? When you cast the object, which is returned by 'getmetadata', back to CollectionOfItems, are you seeing the correct values in the debugger?

Comment: Sadly they are all null in the debugger as well.  It shows x results and has found the correct class.  It also shows param1, param2 etc... but as NULLS

Comment: To clarify I'm breaking straight after result = xmlSer.ReadObject(reader); and looking at what's in result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend just solved this one for me. Here's the the answer for anyone having a similar issue. The namespace also has to be declared in the Item datacontract if it's present in the collectiondatacontract. I.E

```
[DataContract(Name="Item", Namespace = "http://matchingnamespace")] 
    public class Item 
    { 
        [DataMember(Name="Param1")] 
        public string param1{ get; set; } 

        [DataMember(Name="Param2")] 
        public string param2{ get; set; } 
    }
```